Shadow mapping frustum fitting based on Y=0 plane
I am trying to calculate tight fitting of shadow map texture based on camera frustum. Since the camera is always going to be looking down on the Y=0 plane, I thought that can be a good optimization. Using my implementation of something like glm::unproject, I am converting screen pixels of each corner of the screen to world-space points on the Y=0 plane (see illustration).
Now I am trying to figure out the next steps - how to find proper parameters for orthographic perspective and lookAt functions to get the proper depth texture of the shadow map.
Ortho projection matrix 'needs' size (or left, right etc.) and z far/near. View matrix 'needs' position, target and up vector.
I am not sure how to calculate them, I only know so far that they will be related. The size of orthographic projection needs to fit the whole rectangle. Light camera will target  the same target as regular scene camera. Position will be based on light direction scaled to a distance large enough to, again, fit the whole rectangle. Z far should be larger than distance.
Does anyone have any tips how to solve those geometry problems? Or maybe I am overcomplicating things - if that's the case I would also appreciate tips for a better direction.

I just noticed the illustration is a bit wrong, the top-left dot (and lines) should be on the dashed line of course.
